# GlassFish Error : class java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, glassfish

I configured the glassfish server with Eclipse Luna . I downloaded the GlassFish from the market place and configure it correctly . Now when i click Destination Resrouce under the JMS Resource . When I click New it throws me this exception

class java.lang.RuntimeException

and I am not able to add new Destination Resource , same for Connection Factories .  Can anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and I used CLI  to create a new JMS Resources:

use asadmin utility in path\glassfish4\glassfish\bin

in any command prompt.

**To create JMS Connection Factories**

> asadmin> *create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
>   --description "connection factory for XXX"  jms/ConnectionFactory*

**To Create JMS Destination Resources**

> asadmin> *create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Queue --property
>   Name=PhysicalDestination jms/MyQueue*

Follow this Link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ablkb.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use following for creating a **queue connection factory** .

```
create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --description "my connection factory for Task6" jms/QueueConnectionFactory
```